# About Artinian Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I'm studing commutative algebra by the text of Atiyah and Macdonald, and a doubt come at me and I can not prove neither find a counterexample, the problem is:

> If a ring (commutative with identity) has only a finite number of prime ideals then the ring is Artinian (or Noetherian)?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This may be helpful:http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1946-060-00/S0002-9947-1946-0019595-7/S0002-9947-1946-0019595-7.pdf

Comment: The gentleman's name is Atiyah and the book you mention was written by him **and** MacDonald.

Comment: @Georges: actually -- despite what it says on the cover! -- it's Macdonald. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_G._Macdonald

Comment: Dear @Pete, thanks for the definitive reference: I have  had doubts about the spelling for quite some time. I liked the spelling MacDonald because a few years ago, before the Internet and widespread use of computers, it was rather exceptional to see a capital letter inside a word written in lower case .

Comment: Thank you, I was in a hurry when writing this question and I forgot about Macdonald. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $k$ is a field, the ring $k[X_1, X_2,...,X_n,...]/(X_1, X_2^2,...,X_n^n,...)=k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...]$ has $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$ as its only prime ideal but is not artinian, nor even noetherian.

Comment: There you go! (not square zero, though)

Comment: I was hoping you were peacefully sleeping, dear @ Mariano, but I got muddled in my time zones calculations . I feel like those swindlers who keep buying products with the same banknote that they surreptitiously take back at the end of the transaction...

Comment: [@ Users of this site: the preceding friendly teasing comments allude to the fact that Mariano and I often use the above example (or variations of it) to answer questions about non-noetherian rings. And, more seriously, I think mathematicians interested in commutative algebra should add this example to their toolbox: it is quite useful.]

Comment: Thank you! But then I'm missing something... Because in the book(Atiyah and MacDonald) in proposition 8.6 page 90 they say:
_(Let A be a Noetherian local ring, M its maximal ideal. Then ectly one of the following statement is true:
i) $M^{n} = M^{n+1}$ for all n.
ii)$M^{n} = 0 for some n, in wich case A is Artin local ring_
And in the prof they show that if M is the only prime ideal of A then A is Artinian.
I can't see why it is true.

Comment: Dear Charles, the argument in the book does not apply to the ring $A$ in my example, since it is not noetherian. The exact place where the proof in the book collapses for $A$  is the use  of Nakayama: it is illegitimate to invoke this result here because $ M=(x_1,...,x_n,...)$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: I can see it now @GeorgesElencwajg thank you so much for you help!

Comment: You are walcome, dear Charles.